# can't start python interpreter in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, interpreter

im new to emacs and programing overall. Ive downloaded the newest releases in emacs and python. When i open a python file in emacs and i do the swithch to intrepeter command (or any other commands that needs acess to python) i get this reply from emacs mini buffer: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil. When i searched stackoverflow, people with similiar problems are requested to change emacs poython path. People say you should chang your .emacs file to this (setq python-python-command "~/your/python/bin-dir/python"). The problem is i have no clue how you do this in emacs.... i have tried do m-x and then write this code and all combinations of that sentence you can think of. Would be so nice if someone could help me

Answer (score 1):

Not saying that it the right way to solve the problem (I've never had to set the path to Python), but what they are saying is that there is a ~/.emacs file (assuming Linux here) that is loaded and read, when emacs starts up. You would put the line mentioned in that file.

Regarding emacs and Python, take a look at this:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/?utm_source=Python+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=c3a5d1d4a8-Python_Weekly_Issue_220_December_3_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_9e26887fc5-c3a5d1d4a8-312137149

It has info on setting up emacs for Python, which should work out of the box, IIRC.

Comment: no this is a windows computer. in that guide they asume emacs finds python. so it doesent help me. but thanks anyway!

Comment: Well the thing is that i dont know how to do it. what is a setq command, where do i type the command and where is the init file? 
thanks for helping me!